# How do I APPEND or OVERWRITE from a variable in BASH?

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am attempting to create a report using BASH in Ubuntu and the first step I want is asking if the user wants to append to the pre-existing file, however I cannot get the > or >> to work correctly. Is there a better way to accomplish?

I want the variable method just to understand how I could do it. I know I can just hardcode them but I am wanting to use the same variable later in the code so the choice is important

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/tmp/"
#REPORT="$HOSTNAME"_$(date +%Y%m%d%S)
REPORT="$HOSTNAME"_$(date +%Y%m%d)

if [ -f "$DIR""$REPORT" ]
  then
    PS3="Report exists append to record? [y][n]: " 
    options=("Yes" "No")
    select yn in "${options[@]}";
    do
      case $REPLY in
         "y" | "yes" | "Yes" | "YES" )
           echo "You want to add to the file"
           APPEND=">>"
           echo "Ur cmd: echo \"Testing\" $APPEND $DIR$REPORT"
           echo "Testing" $APPEND $DIR$REPORT
           break
           ;;
         "n" | "no" | "No" | "NO" )
           echo "You want to delete the file"
           APPEND='>'
           echo "Ur cmd: echo \"Testing\" $APPEND $DIR$REPORT"
           echo "Testing" $APPEND $DIR$REPORT
           break
           ;;
         * )
           echo "Your choice was not understood"
           ;;
      esac
    done
  else
    echo "Creating $DIR$REPORT"
    touch $DIR$REPORT
fi
```

Comment: I/O is interpretted before variables so this you can't store operators in variables.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `eval`? it is powerful in a way, that it can execute strings as they are formed

Comment: Do not use `eval` for something this trivial. It's a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @chepner: It's a straight forward use in this case! What could ideally go wrong that the interpreter couldn't know? or whatever you meant by `bug waiting to happen`?

Comment: @Inian `DIR="/tmp/foo;bar"`

Comment: You have couple of trivial syntax issues: 1. for the second `case` construct(`"n" | "no" | "No" | "NO" )`), a missing `;;` and 2.  `break` is not allowed in `bash` case statements, unlike C-style switch

Comment: The 1st issue was a copy and paste mistake thanks for that! and the 2nd was there for the select statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a separate file descriptor and then write to that.

```
select yn in Yes No; do
    case $yn in
         "Yes" )
           echo "You want to add to the file"
           echo "Your cmd: exec 3>>$DIR$REPORT"
           exec 3>>"$DIR$REPORT"
           break
           ;;
         "No" )
           echo "You want to delete the file"
           echo "Your cmd: exec 3>$DIR$REPORT"
           exec 3>"$DIR$REPORT"
           break
           ;;
         * )
           echo "Your choice was not understood"
           ;;
    esac
done

echo "Testing" >&3
```

The `exec` statement creates a new file descriptor which either appends or overwrites the log file.  Anything you write to file descriptor 3 will be written to the file.

Also notice how the variable from `select` is used in the `case` statement.  `REPLY` will contain the numeric index of the user's input, which is not what you want here.  (But the case-insensitive and partial string comparison you had there were unnecessary; the `select` statement will return exactly the token you passed as input to it.)

Comment: I also felt compelled to correct the 1d10+ spelling.

Comment: The select is used to create a loop. It works as I wanted it to. The unnecessary partial string comparison does as well?

Comment: When you select the first item in the `select` menu, it will return exactly `Yes`, not `y` or `YES` or `yes`.  So no, you don't need to check for anything except exactly the same value you put in the `select` statement.

Comment: Demo: `select what in bAr FoO; do echo "<$what>$REPLY<"; done <<<1` produces `<bAr>1<` (as well as the `select` output, of course).  Try it with `2`, too.

Comment: I am grateful for your input and opinion however that is not what I have an issue with... the select and case work the way I want them to so no changes will be made.

Comment: !? Did you try this code?  The `exec` decides whether it appends or overwrites the file, and provides an open file handle on file descriptor 3.  Added a brief explanation to the answer.

Comment: Okay, just tried it and the `exec` example you put up is what I needed... It worked better than I could of wanted cause now I just need to call by using `>&3`

Comment: Not that it's something you commonly worry about, but this changes file descriptor 3 for the *entire* script, not just the commands whose write behavior you want to parameterize.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function to wrap the desired operation. For example:

```
  case $REPLY in
     "y" | "yes" | "Yes" | "YES" )
       echo "You want to add to the file"
       log_it () {
           echo "Testing" >> "$1"
       }
       echo "Ur cmd: echo \"Testing\" >> $DIR$REPORT"
       log_it "$DIR$REPORT"
       break
       ;;
     "n" | "no" | "No" | "NO" )
       echo "You want to delete the file"
       log_it () {
           echo "Testing" > "$1"
       }
       echo "Ur cmd: echo \"Testing\" > $DIR$REPORT"
       log_it "$DIR$REPORT"
       break
       ;;
     * )
       echo "Your choice was not understood"
       ;;
  esac
```

Comment: OP has couple of syntax issues, would be good if you can fix it in your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting the output to a file you could pipe it to `tee`. The `tee` command duplicates its input to both stdout and a file. By default it overwrites the given file. This can be changed by using -a or --append. If you don't want to send he output to stdout you can redirect it to `/dev/null`.

See this example:

```
echo "test output" | tee $APPEND $DIR$REPORT >/dev/null
```

`$APPEND` should be either set to `--append` or `""`.